# Makefile: need to executed commands stored in a list

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I was trying to execute the following code.

```
    LIST = 0 1 3 4 5
    targets = $(addprefix rambo, $(LIST))

    all: $(targets)

    $(targets): rambo%: rambo%.sh
        @echo "" > tests/runners/$<
```

The error I am getting is as follows,

```
    make[1]:*** No rule to make target `rambo0.sh', needed by `rambo0'. Stop.
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the code. Basically, I'm trying to create a file dynamically by executing a makefile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you don't have a `rambo0.sh` file in the current directory.

The syntax for a static pattern rule is [`targets ...: target-pattern: prereq-patterns ...`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

Where `targets` are the literal target names, and

> [e]ach target is matched against the target-pattern to extract a part
>   of the target name, called the stem. This stem is substituted into
>   each of the prereq-patterns to make the prerequisite names (one from
>   each prereq-pattern).

Since that seems to be what you are trying to create with that rule I believe you want:

```
targets = $(addsuffix .sh,$(addprefix rambo,$(LIST)))
# Alternatively
# targets = $(patsubst %,rambo%.sh,$(LIST))

$(targets): rambo%.sh :
```

possibly

```
$(targets): rambo%.sh : rambo%
```

if `rambo%` is a file or directory that already exists and is a prerequisite of the shell script file you are trying to create.